Powering an ESP32 from a 1s LiPO
Beginner here. I would like to power an ESP32 (3,3V) from a 1s LiPO and I would like to combine LTC2954-1 Pushbutton On/Off Controller (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2954fb.pdf page 12) with an TPS63802 2-A Buck-boost Converter (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63802.pdf). The OUT+ has a deep discharge protection.
Is the circuit correct?


The LTC2954-1 has an open drain EN output and the TPS63802 has a high impedance EN input. So you need a pullup resistor at the EN signal. The current through this resistor will drain the battery, so a high value is required. The leakage current of both ICs together is typically below 1 µA and the threshold voltage is 1.1 V. So a value of 2.2 Mohm sounds plaisible.
The pins AGND and GND of the TPS63802 must be connected at a quiet point. The layout example on page 28 of the datasheet suggests to connect them directly at the center of the IC.
The inductor XFL4015-471 with 9 A current rating might be an overkill if you only want to feed an ESP32.
